# Are FAR and FRR the same as FPR and FNR, respectively?

Tags: confusion-matrix

FPR = False Positive Rate
FNR = False Negative Rate

FAR = False Acceptance Rate
FRR = False Rejection Rate

Are they the same? if Not, is it possible to calculate FAR and FRR from the confusion matrix?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are the same.

https://books.google.ca/books?id=Go4kBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=FRR+vs+FNR&source=bl&ots=wZQadPKSIM&sig=fXrSks9EKc_ebkMaDuuXBMMqugM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd9dDkvJrTAhXC5YMKHS1LAIIQ6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=FRR%20vs%20FNR&f=false

So in order to calculate their values from the confusion matrix:

```
FAR = FPR = FP/(FP + TN)

FRR = FNR = FN/(FN + TP)

where FP: False positive
      FN: False Negative
      TN: True Negative
      TP: True Positive
```

Comment: Caveat: In statistics a "false rejection" is a Type I or $\alpha$ error, aka a false positive aka rejecting $H_{0}$ when $H_{0}$ is true.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is wrong. [Check](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/588775/237650)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compute FPR and FNR (aka FAR and FRR), here is a Python code for this :

```
from sklearn import metrics

fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, scores)
fnr = 1-tpr
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps  you can look at the confusion matrix as below to see that they are the same :

```
Action -->  Accept    Reject
          |-----------------
Genuine   |  TP    |    FN
          |-----------------
Impostor  |  FP    |    TN
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same.
but confusion metrics can switch between positive features and negative features as we need, Biometrics can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same.

FAR and FRR are calculated over **all attempts**, not individually over positive and negative cases. [Ref1](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Biometrics/XPC9ucFbddsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=FRR%20vs%20FAR&pg=PA56&printsec=frontcover) [Ref2](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Information_Security_Management_Handbook/B0Lwc6ZEQhcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=false%20rejection%20rate&pg=PA876&printsec=frontcover) [Ref3](https://www.recogtech.com/en/knowledge-base/security-level-versus-user-convenience) [Ref4](https://www.webopedia.com/definitions/false-acceptance/)

[image: Ref1]

```
FAR = FP / (TP + FP + TN + FN)
FRR = FN / (TP + FP + TN + FN)
```